# App Store Sign-in Problem

Tags: mac, apple-id, mac-appstore

I just got a MacBook Air, and because it's my first Mac, I set up an Apple ID and account while setting up my MacBook. However, I can't sign-in to the App Store. Here's what happens:

1. Box that says "Sign in to download from the App Store." And I sign-in.
2. Another box says "This Apple ID has not yet been used with the App Store. Please review your account information."
3. I click on "review", a new box says "Sign in required for account creation."
4. So, I enter my password, and the box that says "This Apple ID has not yet been used with the App Store. Please review your account information" comes up again.
5. From here I encounter an endless loop.

From what I found online, setting up payment information should fix this situation, but I have entered payment information and this problem still persists.

Comment: Have you contacted Apple support on this? What did they say? It's possible your account is in a state that only they can correct on their backend.

Comment: Try setting up the Account in System Preferences > Apple ID > Media & Purchases instead of in the "App Store" App. Also: Check if the date and time is set correctly on your Mac.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out finally. After much searching and trial and error, here's literally the only way it would work because none of the other answers on here worked for me: click on your name in settings where it shows you your AppleID and what kind of Apple product you're on, then click on **Media & Purchases**, then click on **View Account** and sign in with AppleID when it prompts you, then follow the steps to review it and choose your payments, and voilà you are able to download apps now.